# Validating Classes and Methods are properly documented (type, arguments, returns, exceptions)?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, pylint, pep8

I run through my code using pep8, pyflakes, and pylint; which all validate the content and format of my Python code.

What I am looking for now is to validate that my Python code is documented properly and completely. For example, if every method, and each of those methods arguments are also documented, as well as expected returns and exceptions. The some true for Classes and Constants and Properties.

I also run my code through Sphinx and Doxygen for document generation.

Comment: To clarify what I am looking for is to assure **well documented** code that follows **[Sphinx and RST syntax guide](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/tutorials/sphinx/docstring_python.html)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pylint has a [Sphinx checker](https://docs.pylint.org/extensions.html) which is disabled by default.